# Best way to load component if object is not undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm very new to react and I am working on an app that is showing certain components like this:

```
{asset.exists && (
  <SomeComponent/>
 )}
```

However, this seems a little clumsy and I keep running into situations where this doesn't seem to be the best way to go about it.

Like the example below:

```
{user.email == asset.email &&
    <SomeComponent
```

This is not working because user is undefined at the moment this code is hit. I figured ComponentDidMount was the correct solution. However, I'm unable to get it working. I'm basically looking for the right way to handle this situation, or a confirmation that ComponentDidMount is the correct approach

Comment: You can check if the user isn't undefined as you render the render the component, 
can your whole code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can provide as many checks as you need by chaining `&&`. For example checking if `user` is truthy AND check that `user.email` is truthy && checking that `user.email` matches `asset.email`:

```
{user && user.email && (user.email === asset.email) &&
 // render something
}
```

You can also consider moving this to a function to contain the logic in centralized place considering you may have complex validations occuring:

```
isValidUser(user, asset) {
  return user && user.email && (user.email === asset.email);
}

// ...

// may be without 'this' depending on location of function
{this.isValidUser(user, asset) &&
   // render something
}
```

Hopefully that helps!

Comment: So, this is the appropriate way to approach this? And thank you for the quick and detailed reply :)

Comment: Yes, I believe It is an appropriate way to approach this. There is no "best" to approach this as it can be personal preference in terms of whether to put logic in the JSX or abstracting it to a separate method. Depending on whether you need to access to `this` in the conditional logic, this can simply be a helper function located outside of the `class`. Some linting tools, may have rules preventing you from putting this kind extended conditional logic inline in JSX. I prefer to put things into methods to keep things "cleaner", but that is just my preference.

Comment: OK, much appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The render method will be called before the component is mounted. In fact render is the method which contains the code to render a component.

So it does not make sense to check for the existence of any property in `componentDidMount`, which you are using in render.

According to the life cycle, `componentWillMount` will be called prior to render and that is the correct place for such checks.

In your case, check for the existence of user and asset in `componentWillMount` and set a state variable to `true` or `false` according to the condition. Use that state in render method to render your component.

Eg :

```
componentWillMount { 
       if (user.email == asset.email) this.setState{flag:true} 
       else this.setState{flag:false} 
     } 
     render() { 
       return( {this.state.flag? <someComponent /> : null} 
     }
```

Comment: Eg : componentWillMount {
          if  (user.email == asset.email) this.setState{flag:true}
          else this.setState{flag:false}
      }

      render() {
        return(
           {this.state.flag? <someComponent /> : null}
    }